# Wireless works, wired doesnt

Tags: windows-7, networking, limited-access

I recently reinstalled Windows 7 RC and now I get limited connection on my wired connection, while the wireless still works perfectly.

I have tried another router, and also other cables, uninstall & reinstall drivers,  so thats not the problem, and the other machines work perfectly on wired, so its definately something on this windows install.

Anyone recognize this problem?

Comment: I had this same problem with Vista. There is a question just like it somewhere on superuser.com but it's for vista

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, if it is seeing something, but you are getting limited connection, I would double check your ip settings and make sure you are getting a DHCP lease and if not, try to assign it manually.

If it is still failing -

I know you will hate me saying it, but I would still check wired drivers-

Download a [linux live cd](http://www.ubuntu.com/getubuntu/download), only use wired and ping the router or any website simply to double check that the socket works (there has been a few questions recently about bad ethernet sockets!)

If it does work from linux then even though you have uninstalled and reinstalled the drivers, it does mean it is a driver issue and all you can do is either try again or wait until newer drivers are released.

If it does not work from linux, it means that the socket is probably dead.

Answer (score 2):

Check whether you have MAC filtering on your router. It may be that you added you wireless but forgot to add your wired connection.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not sharing your wireless connection. If internet sharing is inabled on the wireless connection the wired connection will not work

Answer (score 0):

Try to uncheck TCP/IP v6 on wired connection.